# What does '!const' do in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I came across [documentation wiki for `@pragma("vm:entry-point")`](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/runtime/docs/compiler/aot/entry_point_pragma.md) on Github. It mentions following code snippet:

```dart
@pragma("vm:entry-point")
@pragma("vm:entry-point", true/false)
@pragma("vm:entry-point", !const bool.fromEnvironment("dart.vm.product"))
class C { ... }
```

I know about `const` keyword in Dart. But, what does `!const` do? Is it just to declare that the property is not a constant? Where can I read about its usage and functionality in official documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it means the following:

```
!(const bool.fromEnvironment("dart.vm.product"))
```

I think it means the negative of the bool result.

Two examples:

Code:

```
print(!true);
```

Result:

```
false
```

Code:

```
print(!false);
```

Result:

```
true
```

Comment: hmm, that seems to be it, thanks.

Comment: Makes sense. If its true, the org code could have been written within parentheses to make it clear as: ``!(...)``.

Comment: @OMiShah you are right